# How does loop a lot of URL request work?

Tags: javascript, node.js

For example:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
    requestify.request('http://www.domain.com/' + i)
              .then(function() { // do something; } );
}
```

So, how does NodeJS handle this type of code? It will try to send 100000000 requests or it will request a few request at the same time and put the rest in the queue so that when active request has finished, it will load more request from queue and do it?

I want to ask this question because I run into similiar problem. I load a database of 1,000,000 records of URL that I will later on make a request on each of that URL. So, I don't want my program to hang because it try to request so much at the same time.

Comment: i suggest to use divide and rule and keeps track of completed ones. create new after completion

Comment: You can prioritize the sets of Urls then send the request of another with lower priority when the higher prioirty set completed . Managing a prioirity queue will help you to sort out this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node will fire these requests as fast as it can, it will not wait one to finish and then fire another one.

Javascript is asynchronous, if you want to control the flow you can use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module.

Comment: I don't care about fire one by one. All I care is that will the program hang from trying to running too much request at once, or does NodeJS will queue the request when it reach certain number of request (too much request that it can handle).

Comment: Well, test it! Probably will hang, but I'm not sure. NodeJS has something called  event loop https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-event-loop/

Comment: @invisal depends upon hardware